# Error 500 when exectuting basic phpunit test on laravel

Tags: laravel, http, testing, phpunit

I have a Laravel application running on my local network with Vagrant Homestead.
I tries to implement HTTP tests and I started by creating a basic test like the documentation :

```
/**
 * A basic feature test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testExample()
{
    $response = $this->get('/');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

But when I run the test I receive the error :
**Expected status code 200 but received 500.**

However I can acces my site without any issues.

What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: use `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` to see the actual exception.

Comment: @leoden Could you please share all the content of file `Test Case`?

Comment: @apokryfos thank you, I now have my exception : 
`ErrorException : Route [category.show] not defined. (View: homepage.blade.php)` I can debug it. The problem is that I renamed my routes with locales, eg : **fr.category.show** and **en.category.show**

Answer (score 1):

@ThânLƯƠNG yes, it's the auto-generated test Case :

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class BasicTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

}
```